# How to simultaneously update the color of elements in a SVG when I mouseover elements of a second SVG using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I created two different `SVGs`. One contains a graph with data points, the other one contains three lines. The lines color are supposed to be dependent on the selected data point and I have not managed to get this done yet (more details below). The jsfiddle can be found here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g8hm3uf/5/).

What I would like to do is to change the color of the three lines when I `mouseover` the data points. I managed to change the color of all lines to the same color but would actually like to use the color that is associated to the respective data point but I don't know how I can pass the color data which are stored in `myColors` to the function where I set the lines' color.

The relevant code is shown below. I add a graph with datapoints to `mySvg` and when I `mouseover` the data points, I change their color to black and the color of the lines in the other `SVG` to green. However, instead of changing all lines' color to green, I would actually like to change their colors to the colors defined in `myColors` (see the above linked jsfiddle to find the data). How could I do this?

```
var circles = mySvg.selectAll("circle")
                         .data(lineData)
                         .enter()
                         .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
                       .attr("r", 6)
                       .style("fill", 'red')
                       .on('mouseover', function(d){
                           d3.select(this).style("fill", 'black');
                           d3.select('#myLines').selectAll("line").attr("class","sweepline").style("stroke", 'green');

                           })

                       .on('mouseout', function(d){
                           d3.select(this).style("fill", 'red');

                        });
```

Comment: I got your message ;-) This time I am not sure, if I understand your question. Maybe, that's because I can't get my head around what you are trying to achieve with your code. I am still missing the big picture. Anyway, I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g8hm3uf/6/) with what I think is a solution to your problem. If this resolves your issues I am going to put it in an answer with some further explanations.

Comment: @altocumulus: You are a life saver! :) That is exactly what I was looking for and which I was not able to resolve! Yes, please post it as an answer with additional comments and I am going to accept (and upvote) it. The critical line seems to be 'return d[5][i].color;' so please elaborate on that. Giving the 'big picture' is difficult but that was the best minimal example I could come up with which might indeed seem not too reasonable I have to admit. So thanks a lot for your efforts! I can comment on your answer only by tomorrow so don't be surprised if I do not respond that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many d3 problems this one is easily solved using data binding. Your custom colors could be bound to the lines you append to the second SVG. Since your array `myColors`, consisting of the arrays of custom colors per line, has the same structure as your other arrays like `names`, `x1Val`, `y1Val` and so forth, it can be easily integrated in the data array `coords` used for binding information to your lines:

```
var coords = d3.zip(names, x1Val, y1Val, x2Val, y2Val, myColors);
```

This data per line can later on be used in the `mouseover` event handler for your circles setting the `stroke` style on the lines.

```
.on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
    // ...
    d3.select('#myLines')
        .selectAll("line")
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                return d[5][i].color;
            });
})
```

The callback determines the color by

1. accessing the array of custom colors, which is at position 5 of the data array bound to the lines, hence `d[5]`,
2. getting the `i`th object of this array of colors. The `i` is the index of this circle, which is passed as parameter to the event handler and made available to the `stroke` callback by a closure,
3. getting property `.color` from this object

Check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g8hm3uf/7/) for a working example.

---

Furthermore, I have updated the `mouseout` handler to delete the previously set `stroke` style causing the lines to be reset to their default color set by class `sweepline`. This behaviour, at least to my eyes, seemed to be missing.

```
d3.select('#myLines')
    .selectAll("line")
        .style("stroke", null);
```

Comment: Very, very helpful, thanks again! Seems I have to invest much more time on data structures. For my actual problem, I will have to read these data from a CSV or JSON file. Challenge will then be to get the data structure 'coords' from these files but I guess there are smart ways to do this. Thanks once more and see you at the next question! ;)